# How can you record video and audio with Android Media Player

Tags: android, audio, video, xamarin, mediarecorder

I want to record a video, including audio, in my Android app. So far I have been able to record the video using code from elsewhere on this site, but I have been unable to include any audio. How can I record both?
The code I am using (Xamarin C#) to set up the media recorder is below. It is a bit rough and ready at the moment.

```
    private void InitRecorder(Surface surface)
    {
        // It is very important to unlock the camera before doing setCamera
        // or it will results in a black preview
        if (mCamera == null)
        {
            mCamera = Camera.Open();
            mCamera.Unlock();
        }

        if (mMediaRecorder == null)
            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mMediaRecorder.SetPreviewDisplay(surface);
        mMediaRecorder.SetCamera(mCamera);

        mMediaRecorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Default);
        mMediaRecorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mpeg4);
        mMediaRecorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.SetVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
        mMediaRecorder.SetVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.SetVideoSize(640, 480);
        mMediaRecorder.SetOutputFile(VIDEO_PATH_NAME);

        try
        {
            mMediaRecorder.Prepare();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // This is thrown if the previous calls are not called with the 
            // proper order

        }

        mInitSuccesful = true;
    }
```

The permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**You need to set your audio sources.**
**Add below code to your InitRecorder() method.**

```
mMediaRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
mMediaRecorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AmrNb);
```